# search multidimensional array with mixed data types, echo back result

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, echo

I have a php array with mixed data types (arrays, ints, strings). I want to search the array for a match contained within an array of mixed data types as show below.

my test array

```
$arrActors =[0 => [ 
    'actorName' => "heath ledger",
    'actorAlias' => [],
    'actorGender' => 1,
    'actorNoms' => ["angel", "john constantine"]
],
1 => [ 
    'actorName' => "Michael pare",
    'actorAlias' => ["mikey", "that guy"],
    'actorGender' => 1,
    'actorNoms' => ["cyclops", "slim", "eric the red"]
    ]
];
```

If the needle is set to an element and that element is found to exists in actorNoms, I want to echo back the name of the associated actor (actorName). In the below example, I have attempted to find cyclops (actorNoms) return the name of the actor, Michael Pare (actorName) who is associated with him.

My Attempt to find actorNoms and return the actors name

```
$needle = 'cyclops';
foreach($arrActors as $haystack) 
{   
    if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) { 
        echo $haystack['actorNoms'] . '<br />' ;
    }else{
        echo 'nothing found<br />';//echo something so i know it ran
    }
}
```

My attempt returns fails as it echo's 'nothing found'. How do I echo back the name of the actor Michael Pare when searching for cyclops.

Thank you for any help given. I have tried to format my code correctly for ease of use. I have searched Stack, Google and other sources for several hours now trying to find a solution I can understand. I am not very adept, but I promise I am learning and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `in_array()` only searches the top level, it won't do what you want as it currently is. You'll need to run a loop (`foreach` / `for`). (*since `actorNoms` is an array*). Try changing it to `if(in_array($needle, $haystack['actorNoms'])) { ....`

Comment: if you're just going to search inside `actorNoms` then just explicitly point it to that inside `in_array`, then echo actor name.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - in most instances i will actually search explicitly (that means i would search 'actorName' and thus call it specifically yes?). But I want to understand how to do more so as to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) { 
    echo $haystack['actorNoms'] . '<br />' ;
}
```

try this:

```
if(in_array($needle, $haystack['actorNoms'])) { 
    echo $haystack['actorName'] . '<br />' ;
}
```

what you did was search the `$haystack` which is the main array for the actors.

`in_array` doesn't search nested arrays automatically for multidimensional arrays, hence you need to specify the area in which you would search: `in_array($haystack['actorNoms'])`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it worked and it is appreciated. As it  was the first received, I selected it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$needle = 'cyclops';
foreach($arrActors as $haystack) 
{   
    if(in_array($needle, $haystack['actorNoms'])) { 
        echo $haystack['actorName'] . '<br />' ;
    }
}
```

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), works for one level array only. So every time it goes through first level array, where as 'actorNoms' is sub array under firstlevel array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this this give you parent index using this index you will get the data

```
$arrActors = array( array( 
    'actorName' => "heath ledger",
    'actorAlias' => array(),
    'actorGender' => 1,
    'actorNoms' => array("angel", "john constantine")
),array(

    'actorName' => "Michael pare",
    'actorAlias' => array("mikey", "that guy"),
    'actorGender' => 1,
    'actorNoms' => array("cyclops", "slim", "eric the red")
    )
);


print_r( getParent_id("cyclops",$arrActors));
function getParent_id($child, $stack) {
        foreach ($stack as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                // If the current element of the array is an array, recurse it and capture the return
                $return = getParent_id($child, $v);

                // If the return is an array, stack it and return it
                if (is_array($return)) {
                    return array($k => $return);
                }
            } else {
                // Since we are not on an array, compare directly
                if (preg_match("/$child/",$v)) {
                    // And if we match, stack it and return it
                    return array($k => $child);
                }
            }
        }

        // Return false since there was nothing found
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I attempted this, but it returned a fatal error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getParentStack(). Can you share that function?

Comment: Now i have modify the function try with updated code or "getParentStack" replace with "getParent_id".